# Creating a database using Access?

Tags: database, excel, ms-access

I recently tookover a non-profit program for senior citizens called "Meals on Wheels", perhaps your city has one too.

Currently it is a very cumbersome routine of manually checking tags for each person who gets the meals and seeing if they can't eat certain things and what days of the week they get delivery.

I would love to computerize this in order to eliminate not only mistakes but make it run faster and smoother.

The tags contain names, address, foods they can't eat and days of the week.

Is there a way to computerize this? We have a meal menu run on excel if that helps.

I was advised to try using MS Access, but, I have never used it before, would this be the program we would need to do this?

Thanks guys

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Yes, Access could do it (along with a whole host of other databases & tools).

Comment: For simple needs, if you are comfortable with Excel and don't know anything about Access, Excel might be an easier solution to start with.

Comment: So would I just create a table in Excel containing every client, then run a query for example for everyone who get meals on say Monday?   If so, how would I set up the fields for that?

Comment: Your description is vague enough that it is difficult to know what the right design would be, but the few things that might help if you decide to use Excel are: pivot tables, lookup formulas (vlookup, hlookup, countif, sumif). I suggest you have a look at those and start building something. You will then be able to ask specific questions that will hopefully attract specific and useful answers.

Comment: Have you tried contacting other groups providing “Meals on Wheels”?  I would be surprised if you were the first to consider computerisation.  The system you want may already exist and be available for a nominal sum.

Comment: You might look into: http://www.prncomp.com/MealsOnWheels.aspx

Comment: I found this discussion in a search http://forums.techsoup.org/cs/community/f/20/p/21705/21705.aspx#21705, which mentions this http://www.mealservicesoftware.com/purchasing.htm, which is apparently free for non-profit organizations, including support.

Answer (score 2):

Access might be useful if you have a large number of people to cater for, or if you are constantly entering new information. It sounds as if Excel might be more useful in your case. A couple of things that might help you are conditional formatting and filtering.

---

**This will highlight a client if they are due for a delivery today:**

Create a spreasheet with people's names in column **A** starting on **row 2** (headings are optional in row 1, but the formula below starts with row 2 anyway), put the days they have delivery in column **B** with the full day name written out like this **Sunday, Wednesay, Friday** or whatever. In the remaining column you could put addresses, foods, etc
Click on cell **A2** and drag to select all the customers' names, the days, addresses, etc.
Click on **Conditional Formatting** at the top of the Excel window.

Click on **New Rule**

Selct **Use a Formula to determine which cells to format**

In the box labelled **Format values where this formula is true** copy and paste this formula:

```
=COUNTIF($B2,"*"&TEXT(WEEKDAY(TODAY(),1),"dddd")&"*")>0
```

Still in the dialog box, click the **Format** button, select the **Fill** tab and select a bright colour. Click **OK** to confirm the colour, then **OK** to save the new rule, then **OK** to apply the conditional format.

(This formula gets the date with **TODAY()**, converts it to the **WEEKDAY()** number (using Sunday as day 1), converts the day number to **TEXT** with the format "dddd" (Sunday instead of "ddd", which is Sun),  **COUNTIF()** will only count the cell if it contains the day (giving 1 or 0), if it contains the day then '1 is greater than 0' becomes TRUE and the cell is conditionally formatted.)

---

If you want the formula to work for other dates instead of today you could replace the TODAY() part with a cell reference, say G1, then type the date you want in cell G1:

```
=COUNTIF($B3,"*"&TEXT(WEEKDAY($G$1,1),"dddd")&"*")>0
```

Then type a date like 22/5/12 in cell G1

If clients get deliveries on the same day every week, then to see who gets meals on Thursdays you could type Thursday in G1 & shorten the formula to:

```
=COUNTIF($B3,"*"&$G$1&"*")>0
```

---

**To create a filter that displays only clients due that day instead of just highlighting them:**

Create a spreadsheet laid out as before (starting in row 2, with the client's Delivery Days in column B - Monday, Thursday, Saturday) and, instead of Conditional Formatting, paste the formula into a cell in row **2** and use autofill by hovering the mouse over the bottom-right of the cell with the formula so the cursor changes to a **+** and double-clicking. You should get a column of TRUE and FALSE values, as long as you don't have any empty rows. (If you need empty rows, click and drag the **+** down instead.)

Go to the **Data** tab at the top of the Excel window and select the **Filter** button. Some down arrows should appear at the top of your columns. Select the down arrow above the TRUE/FALSE column and select only the TRUE checkbox. To display all clients again, select the same down arrow again and select **Select All**. Any time you add a new client to the spreadsheet, hover over a cell in the formula column and double-click the **+** autofill again to add the formula to the new client's row.

You could use both methods together to highlight *and* filter without a problem

---

There are other things that could help, but it depends on how you operate. You could write a column of 'todays ingredients' and use Conditional Formatting to highlight someone in red when an ingredient matches something they cannot eat. This could be risky if someone doesn't eat fish and you put haddock in the ingredients list because they will not match, of course!

If you want free Excel masterclasses I recommend YouTube's
[Bill Jelen - 'Mr Excel'](http://www.youtube.com/user/bjele123/videos) and [ExcelIsFun](http://www.youtube.com/user/ExcelIsFun/videos)